# Is a general "How do you debug on <framework/platform>" question okay?

Tags: discussion, questions, debugging-questions

I wanted to ask a general question on how to go about debugging Parse.com Cloud code.

But I felt like that was too open-ended for StackOverflow, so I ended up posting about it over here instead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/ZGEC78wK8D4

Did I do the right thing in not posting it on StackOverflow, or was it perfectly acceptable to post that here?